# How to write code for addition of two numbers and then display the sum in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, tasm, dosbox

I'm using Assembly language x86 in TASM DOS environment. How to display the sum of 2 numbers after operate addition?

Already tried to do code on add two numbers:

```
 .data 
   num1 db 75
   num2 db 130
   add1 db ?

 .code
   start:
     mov ax, seg num1
     mov ds, ax

     ;addition
     mov al, num1
     mov bl, num2
     add al, bl
     mov add1, al

     mov ah, 4CH
     int 21h

   end start
```

Where the code above add 75 and 130.
Now i just want to know how to display out the sum in the "add1".

Comment: You need to write a short loop that will convert your binary result to a string of ASCII characters, and send the address of that to the OS.